# Google Groupsの会話をGoogle Apps Scriptから検索するには

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups

自社内でGoogle Workspaceを利用しており、Google GroupsやGoogle Apps Scriptを用いています。
Google Groupsのグループについて、指定した範囲とキーワードでGoogle Apps Scriptから該当するものを検討したいです。
やり方を教えてください。

ただし、Google Apps Scriptから検索用アカウントを作成し、対象のグループへ検索用アカウントを追加し、検索用アカウントのGMailに対してGoogle Apps ScriptからGmailApp.searchで検索する方法以外でお願いします。